# PHP: Instgarm redirect my links detect unsafe

Tags: php, redirect, header, instagram

I create shortener link website

This is my code for redirect websites :

```
$url =  $result[0]['linkUrl'];
header("Location: $url", TRUE, 301);
exit();
```

This code work fine everywhere, but in `instagram` i get unsafe error

Why ?

Comment: have you tried urlencode your url before setting it as a header?

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa yes i try it. but nor work

Comment: Please, dump the url and provide

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa this is actual url : `https://name.com`

Comment: Little bit strange. Code: 

        `$url =  'https://name.com';`
       ` header("Location: $url", TRUE, 301);`
       ` exit();`

works fine >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode)

```
$url =  rawurlencode($result[0]['linkUrl']);
```

Also make sure your URL has `https://` at the beginning of the URL